# Rindler space action of massless scalar field

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-tensor

[This document](https://www.thphys.uni-heidelberg.de/~witkowski/curved/talk8.pdf) talks about transforming the action 
$$S[\phi]=\int g^{\alpha\beta} \phi_{,\alpha} \phi_{,\beta} \sqrt{-g}\ d^2x$$
to Rindler coordinates. I.e. replacing

$$g_{\alpha\beta}\rightarrow \tilde{g}_{\alpha\beta}= \Omega^2(t,x)g_{\alpha\beta}$$

Doing so would cause

> the determinant $\sqrt{-g}$ [to pick] up a factor $\Omega^2(t,x)$ which cancels the factor of $\Omega^{-2}$ from the inverse metric $g^{\alpha\beta}$. [page 2]

Which "inverse metric" is the text talking about?  I do not see why $\sqrt{-g}$ would get a factor of $\Omega^{-2}$, because of the square root. Thusm a factor of $\Omega$ would remain in the action.

Can someone clarify this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The “inverse metric” is the fully-contravariant tensor $g^{\mu\nu}$. Viewed as a matrix it is the inverse of the fully-covariant tensor $g_{\mu\nu}$, because

$$g^{\mu\lambda}g_{\lambda\nu}=\delta^\mu_\nu.$$

If $g_{\mu\nu}$ picks up a factor of $\Omega^2$, then $g^{\mu\nu}$ must pick up a factor of $\Omega^{-2}$.

As for the scaling of the determinant, this two-dimensional metric tensor is

$$\begin{pmatrix}
g_{tt} & g_{tx} \\
g_{xt} & g_{xx}
\end{pmatrix}$$

and the scaled metric is

$$\begin{pmatrix}
\Omega^2g_{tt} & \Omega^2g_{tx} \\
\Omega^2g_{xt} & \Omega^2g_{xx}
\end{pmatrix}$$

so it is obvious that the determinant picks up a factor $\Omega^4$ and the square of the determinant thus picks up a factor of $\Omega^2$, as the document said (and not $\Omega^{-2}$, as you said).

Comment: I also asked this question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/486470/transformation-of-g-mu-nu-partial-mu-f-partial-nu-f could you please clarify why there is no additional factor from the derivatives in this case?

Comment: The conformal invariance the paper is talking about involves a scaling of the metric, not of the coordinates.